# Leap Motion Visual Studio Setup Error, error MSB3073. What do I do?

Tags: c++, compiler-construction

I was trying to add this

```
  xcopy $(LEAP_SDK)\lib\x64\Leapd.dll "$(TargetDir)"
  xcopy $(LEAP_SDK)\lib\x64\msvcp100d.dll "$(TargetDir)"
  xcopy $(LEAP_SDK)\lib\x64\msvcr100d.dll "$(TargetDir)"
```

to the "Command Line" in the "Post-Build Event", but when I tried; it gave me an error:

```
1>  InteractionContextSample.vcxproj -> C:\Users\ssg\Desktop\Working On\3 Leap Motion\InteractionContextSample_1_Unedited\Debug\InteractionContextSample.exe
1>  Invalid number of parameters
1>  Invalid number of parameters
1>  Invalid number of parameters
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V110\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(134,5): error MSB3073: The command "xcopy C:\Users\ssg\Desktop\Working On\3 Leap Motion\LeapSDK+Examples_hotfix_public_win_x86_0.8.1+6221 (1)\LeapSDK\lib\x86\Leapd.dll "C:\Users\ssg\Desktop\Working On\3 Leap Motion\InteractionContextSample_1_Unedited\Debug\"
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V110\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(134,5): error MSB3073: xcopy C:\Users\ssg\Desktop\Working On\3 Leap Motion\LeapSDK+Examples_hotfix_public_win_x86_0.8.1+6221 (1)\LeapSDK\lib\x86\msvcp100d.dll "C:\Users\ssg\Desktop\Working On\3 Leap Motion\InteractionContextSample_1_Unedited\Debug\"
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V110\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(134,5): error MSB3073: xcopy C:\Users\ssg\Desktop\Working On\3 Leap Motion\LeapSDK+Examples_hotfix_public_win_x86_0.8.1+6221 (1)\LeapSDK\lib\x86\msvcr100d.dll "C:\Users\ssg\Desktop\Working On\3 Leap Motion\InteractionContextSample_1_Unedited\Debug\"
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V110\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(134,5): error MSB3073: 
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V110\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(134,5): error MSB3073: :VCEnd" exited with code 4.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

The guide off of Leap Motion website said to do this, to set up a project for Visual Studio 2012.
Any help is appreciated!

Comment: It looks like you need quotes around both arguments to xcopy since there are spaces in the path. ex: `xcopy "$(LEAP_SDK)\lib\x64\Leapd.dll" "$(TargetDir)"`